# Redirect powershell output and errors to console (in real-time) and to a variable

Tags: powershell, error-handling, io-redirection, tee

I would like to redirect the output of a command in PowerShell, following these rules:

- The command is stored to a variable
- Output must be written to the console in real-time (i.e. "ping" results), including errors
- Output must be stored to a variable, including errors (real-time is not mandatory here)

Here are my tests, assuming:

```
$command = "echo:"
```

to test errors redirection, and:

```
$command = "ping 127.0.0.1"
```

to test real-time output.

1. Output is written in real-time, errors are not redirected at all

   ```
   Invoke-Expression $command 2>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable out_content
   ```
2. Output is written in real-time, errors are only redirected to the console

   ```
   Invoke-Expression ($command 2>&1) | Tee-Object -Variable out_content
   Invoke-Expression $command | Tee-Object -Variable out_content 2>&1
   ```
3. Output is not written in real-time, errors are correctly redirected to both

   ```
   (Invoke-Expression $command) 2>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable out_content
   ```

Is it possible to get those rules working together?

Comment: `. { Invoke-Expression $command } 2>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable out_content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some **general recommendations** up front:

- **[`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)**, because it can be a security risk and introduces quoting headaches; there are usually better and safer solutions available; best to form a habit of avoiding `Invoke-Expression`, unless there is no other solution.
- **There is never a reason to use `Invoke-Expression` to simply execute an external program with arguments**, such as `ping 127.0.0.1`; just invoke it *directly* - support for such direct invocations is a core feature of any shell, and PowerShell is no exception.
- I**f you do need to store a command in a *variable* or pass it as an *argument*** for *later* invocation, **use *script blocks* (`{ ... }`)**; e.g., instead of `$command = 'ping 127.0.0.1'`, use `$command = { ping 127.0.0.1 }`, and invoke that script block on demand with either `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-), or `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).
  When calling *external programs*, the two operators exhibit the same behavior; when calling *PowerShell-native commands*, `&` executes the code in a *child scope*, whereas `.` (typically) executes in the caller's *current* scope.

---

**That `Invoke-Expression $command 2>&1` doesn't work as expected looks like a *bug*** (as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.3) and has been reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10476).

As for a **workaround** for your problem:

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as countless times before, has provided a solution in a comment on the question:

```
& { Invoke-Expression $command } 2>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable out_content
```

`{ ... }` is a script-block literal that contains the `Invoke-Expression` call, and it is invoked with `&`, the call operator, which enables applying stream-redirection expression `2>&1` *to the `&` call*, which bypasses the bug.

<sup>If `$command` contained a PowerShell-native command that you wanted to execute directly in the current scope, such as a function definition, you'd use `.` instead of `&`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I modified my code to store commands as `ScriptBlocks` instead of `Strings`, it was not mandatory to use `Invoke-Expression`.